# yarn dev : node_modules/node/bin/node: not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm running next js in a windows machine but it shows the file path in linux. Not sure why the path starts like a linux file path any idea. I have set the node file path in env variable. But getting the below error.

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ next dev
/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node: 8: /mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer the thing when i was trying to debug some error unfortunately ran the below command without understanding the meaning:

```
npm config set script-shell bash
```

you can see the scripting is mapped to bash so the node started to take the path in the linux format. Changed the above scripting to

```
npm config set script-shell cmd
```

It made the application to work.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to follow these steps:

1. Download git-bash
2. Install nvm
3. Install node and npm via nvm

Cheers :)